# MediaPlayer Notification Controls Not Working

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I have the following code that creates an ongoing notification for my music player

```
private Notification buildNotification(String title, String artist) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_playing);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicPlayer.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

RemoteViews compactNotification = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notfication_custom_layout);
RemoteViews expandedNotification = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_expanded_layout);

Intent previousTrackIntent = new Intent(Music.getContext(), MusicService.class);
previousTrackIntent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_REWIND);
PendingIntent previousTrackPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, previousTrackIntent, 0);

Intent playPauseTrackIntent = new Intent(Music.getContext(), MusicService.class);
playPauseTrackIntent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK);
PendingIntent playPauseTrackPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, playPauseTrackIntent, 0);

Intent nextTrackIntent = new Intent(Music.getContext(), MusicService.class);
nextTrackIntent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_SKIP);
PendingIntent nextTrackPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, nextTrackIntent, 0);

Intent stopServiceIntent = new Intent(Music.getContext(), MusicService.class);
stopServiceIntent.setAction(MusicService.ACTION_STOP);
PendingIntent stopServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, stopServiceIntent, 0);

if (mState == State.Playing) {
    compactNotification.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_base_play, R.drawable.ic_action_pause_dark);
    expandedNotification.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_expanded_base_play, R.drawable.ic_action_pause_dark);
} else if (mState == State.Paused || mState == State.Stopped) {
    compactNotification.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_base_play, R.drawable.ic_action_play_dark);
    expandedNotification.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_expanded_base_play, R.drawable.ic_action_play_dark);
}

compactNotification.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_base_line_one, title);
compactNotification.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_base_line_two, artist);

expandedNotification.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_base_line_one, title);
expandedNotification.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_base_line_two, artist);

compactNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_play, playPauseTrackPendingIntent);
expandedNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_play, playPauseTrackPendingIntent);

compactNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_next, nextTrackPendingIntent);
expandedNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_next, nextTrackPendingIntent);

compactNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_previous, previousTrackPendingIntent);
expandedNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_previous, previousTrackPendingIntent);

expandedNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_expanded_base_collapse, stopServicePendingIntent);
compactNotification.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_base_collapse, stopServicePendingIntent);

//Set the album art.
expandedNotification.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_expanded_base_image, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.selena_gomez));
compactNotification.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notification_base_image, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.selena_gomez));

//Attach the shrunken layout to the notification.
notificationBuilder.setContent(compactNotification);

//Build the notification object.
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

//Attach the expanded layout to the notification and set its flags.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    notification.bigContentView = expandedNotification;

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE |
        Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR |
        Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

return notification;
```

}

The notification appears correctly but the controls dont work even thought the controls are well defined.

Is there something else I need to enable or assign to get the controls to work?

Comment: Have you checked logcat for possible exceptions?

Comment: @patwanjau there are no exceptions on the logcat.

Comment: Then ensure that you register your `MusicService` as a receiver in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is 5 years late, but I found that Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE still shows the controls, but doesn't allow them to be "clickable". I found the same behavior when I showed the notification with startForeground(int,notification);

If I just used the following flags (Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT), then call stopForeground(false); and then nm.notify(int, notification); it works as expected.